# Log in with Requests module in Python for a page that has a two-step login?

Tags: python, python-requests

The website I need to login to has an initial page for only entering the username and a second where I just enter the password, but the username block is still displayed with the username filled in.
I post the username and password as such:

```
session = requsts.session()

prelogin_url = ''
result = session.get(prelogin_url)
payload = {'j_username': 'username'}

result = session.post(
    prelogin_url,
    data = payload
)

# page 2
login_url = ''
result = session.get(login_url)
password = {'j_password': 'password'}

result = session.post(
    login_url,
    data = password
)
```

When I check the content, it shows me that the login failed. There are no tokens.
What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you need to do a GET on the second step login page before doing the second POST?

Comment: Thanks, good point. I added that in. Still am getting a login error after I take these steps and do a get request on the home page.

Comment: The second login page pre-fills the username.  Perhaps you need to do that yourself?  If that was being performed by on-page javascript, requests won't do that.

Comment: Have you looked at the source of both login pages in a browser?  Perhaps there are some hidden fields such as a CSRF token?

Comment: Thanks John Gordon. I added the username field again in the second post, and still no luck. Both login pages has no CSRF token, but appears on the home page after I login manually.

Comment: I may just try this with Selenium if there's a method to do this with that module.